# Copy filenames from synchronizing perspective in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, copy-paste

Is there a way to copy all file names listed in a synchronizing perspective ?
(i mean the list of files to synchronize)

thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't copy multiple file names at once. But you copy multiple files if you want.

Comment: isn't there any other way ? even outside Eclipse ?